# Can I bind 3 comboboxes to one form?

Tags: ms-access

Each of three columns: cust_id, cust_name, cust_company are in are in three combo boxes, each returning the cust_id as the key. When any of the combo boxes has a value chosen, I'd like to update a sub-form's data. I'm new to access, but my background is programming. I've yet to figure out where anything is beyond create wizards and property sheets, so be gentle.

Thanks!

Jimbus

Comment: You meant bind to one field, not form. The answer is Yes. However, if comboboxes are used to enter/select search criteria, they should be UNBOUND. If you want to edit field data then bind to field.

Comment: Are you trying to update `sub-form` or filter sub-form data based on selection of those 3 combo boxes?

Comment: I want a tabbed subform. One with a customer's info (name, company, adress...). One with order info and the last with shipping info. All of it tied to the customer ID obtained from one of the combo boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use three subforms:

- Make the main form unbound
- Place the three comboboxes to select `cust_id` on the main form
- Place the tab control on the main form
- Place a subform on each of the three pages of the tab control

On the main form, for each of the subforms, set these properties of the *subform control* that holds it:

```
LinkChildFields:  The foreign key of the subform (cust_id)
LinkMasterFields: The combobox used to select cust_id for the subform
```

Zero code.

Comment: This seems like this would tie one combo box to one tab/sub-form. I'd like each tab/sub-form to pull info from only one of the combo boxes, whichever one that happens to  have a value selected

Comment: Then let the comboxes set a value in a textbox and use this as the `LinkMasterField`.